# Django filter for a specific user

Tags: mysql, django, filter

I want to get the query that excludes the notes if that userid has in that notification the status=1. 
what it does is exclude that notification if somebody has status=1 and the user is in the database.

```
notes = Notification.objects.filter(**condition).\
    exclude(Q(notification_user__status_id__status=1) & Q(notification_user__user_id__userid=userid)).\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a little cleaner for you to first query on the group of users you want to exclude and then pass that entire group of users to the notifications query:

```
users = User.objects.filter(status=1, id=1)
notes = Notification.objects.filter(**condition).exclude(user__in=users)
```

Comment: Needed to change a little bit to correspond the database model, used your idea and it worked